# Displaying the result of mmioRead

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7, wav

After locating the data chunk using mmioDescend, then how i suppose to read and display the sample data into for example into a memo in delphi 7?

I have follow the step like open the file, locating the riff, locating the fmt, locating data chunk.

```
if (mmioDescend(HMMIO, @ckiData, @ckiRIFF, MMIO_FINDCHUNK) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR) then
SetLength(buf, ckiData.cksize);
mmioRead(HMMIO, PAnsiChar(buf), ckiData.cksize);
```

I use mmioRead too but i don't know how to display the data.Can anyone help give an example how to use the mmioRead and then display the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd probably read into a buffer that was declared using a more appropriate type.

For example, suppose your data are 16 bit integers, `Smallint` in Delphi. Then declare a dynamic array of `Smallint`.

```
var
  buf: array of Smallint;
```

Then allocate enough space for the data:

```
Assert(ckiData.cksize mod SizeOf(buf[0])=0);
SetLength(buf, ckiData.cksize div SizeOf(buf[0]));
```

And then read the buffer:

```
mmioRead(HMMIO, PAnsiChar(buf), ckiData.cksize);
```

Now you can access the elements as `Smallint` values.

If you have different element types, then you can adjust your array declaration. If you don't know until runtime what the element type is you may be better off with `array of Byte` and then using pointer arithmetic and casting to access the actual content.

I'd say that the design of the interface to `mmioRead` is a little weak. The buffer isn't really a string. It's probably best considered as a byte array. But perhaps because C does not have separate byte and character types, the function is declared as taking a pointer to char array. Really the Delphi translation would be better exposing a pointer to byte or even better in my view, a plain untyped `Pointer` type.

---

I assumed that you were struggling with interpreting the output of `mmioRead` since that was the code that you included in the question. But, according to now deleted comments, your question is a GUI question.

You want to add content to a memo. Do it like this:

```
Memo1.Clear;
for i := low(buf) to high(buf) do
  Memo1.Items.Add(IntToStr(buf[i]));
```

If you want to convert to floating point then, still assuming 16 bit signed data, do this:

```
Memo1.Clear;
for i := low(buf) to high(buf) do
  Memo1.Items.Add(FormatFloat('0.00000', buf[i]/32768.0));//show 5dp
```

Comment: can i ask 1 more, why i get **NAN** value when trying to read .wav file and directly store it sample data in **double**? weren't it allowed? i'm just curious.

Comment: That happens when your reading code is wrong and you read data that is not actually a double.